# Match debit and credit values in bank reconciliation using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, matching

We have many transactions (sales, credits, debits, etc.) with related parties but seldom send payments. Once in a while, I would like to reduce the number of open items by identifying positive and negative amounts that net to zero and clear those items.

Currently, I dump the open items into Excel, sort by value, and manually play with items until I get a combination that is nearly zero (it seems we never find a combination that is exactly zero).

Since my goal is to minimize the number of open items, not only do I need to net as close to zero as possible (a few dollars negative or positive can be simply written off), but I also try to include as many transactions as possible in the final answer. That is, netting two transactions for +5 and -5 is fine but netting four transactions for +1, +2, +2 and -5 is better.

The below code is able to find and highlight values matching -5 and +5. Is it possible to highlight multiple value +1, +2, +2 and -5

```
Sub sum_groups()
Dim CurrentCell As Range, CurrentRange As Range, rg As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim ColorIndex As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ColorIndex = 6

Set CurrentCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
Set CurrentRange = CurrentCell

'Loop until end of list
Do Until CurrentCell.Row = LastRow

    'Loop until 0 group is found
    Do Until WorksheetFunction.sum(CurrentRange) = 0
        'Break loop if last row is reached
        If CurrentCell.Row + CurrentRange.Rows.Count > LastRow Then Exit Do
        Set CurrentRange = CurrentRange.Resize(CurrentRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    Loop
    
    If WorksheetFunction.sum(CurrentRange) = 0 Then
        'Alternate color
        If ColorIndex = 6 Then
            ColorIndex = 4
        ElseIf ColorIndex = 4 Then
            ColorIndex = 6
        End If
        
        'Enter 0 and change color
        For Each rg In CurrentRange
            rg.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
            rg.Offset(0, 1) = 0
        Next rg
        
        'Move to next cell after current range
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(CurrentRange.Rows.Count)
    Else
        'Move to next cell after current tested cell
        Set CurrentCell = CurrentCell.Offset(1)
    End If
    
    'Reset CurrentRange
    Set CurrentRange = CurrentCell

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your problem is similar to the "knapsack problem" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem and there's no easy general solution...

Comment: How many open items are we talking about? You're looking at finding every possible combination of items valued smaller than the target item, multiplied by the number of open items. That quickly becomes a very steep exponential curve.